# How can I set XACT_ABORT using JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, groovy

I am using a hibernate entity that maps to a view in MS SQLServer.  The view consists of data selected from a table on a linked server.  I am able to successfully query this view using JPQL.  However, when I try to update the view using entityManager.merge(myEntity), I get the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Unable to start a nested transaction for OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "DBNAME". A nested transaction was required because the XACT_ABORT option was set to OFF.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)...

I need to set XACT_ABORT to ON so that SQLServer can rollback the entire transaction if an error occurs.  I was able to work around the issue using a native query, but it's not really ideal.

```
    String queryString = """set xact_abort on; update table_name set column1 = :column1, column2 = :column2 where id = :id"""
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString)
    query.setParameter("column1", column1)
    query.setParameter("column2", column2)
    query.setParameter("id", id)
    query.executeUpdate()
```

**Is there any way I can configure hibernate/JPA/JPAVendorAdaptor to execute the "set xact_abort on" for every merge/persist so I don't have to use a native query?**

Here is my hibernate configuration:

```
@Resource
DataSource dataSource

@Bean
JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter(){
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(database:Database.SQL_SERVER)
}

@Bean
AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(dataSource:dataSource, jpaVendorAdapter:vendorAdapter())
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.entity")
    return em
}

@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory:entityManagerFactory().getObject())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a hibernate interceptor to append "set xact_abort on" for every insert and update statement.

Here's my interceptor:

```
class XactAbortInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{
   String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
      if(sql.startsWith("insert") || sql.startsWith("update"))
         sql = "set xact_abort on; " + sql
      return sql
   }
}
```

Here's where I register the interceptor:

```
@Bean
AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(dataSource:dataSource, jpaVendorAdapter:vendorAdapter())
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.mycompany.entity")
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(["hibernate.ejb.interceptor": XactAbortInterceptor.class.name])
    return em
}
```

Now all calls to entityManager.merge(myObject) or entityManager.persist(myObject) will set xact_abort to on.

Hopefully this helps someone else experiencing the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

i have to register the interceptor Class XactAbortInterceptor in persitence.xml file